Why does Electrum's createnewaddress() only return legacy addresses?
Why does Electrum's createnewaddress() (or "Create Request") only return legacy addresses? How do I make it create bech32 addresses?

Electrum stores whether to create legacy addresses or segwit addresses at the wallet level (it is part of the Electrum seed itself), hence each wallet is configured to only produce legacy addresses or only segwit addresses. It sounds like the wallet you are using is a legacy address wallet.

I imported a mixture of address types to the wallet.

createnewaddress() isn't going to give you addresses that have been imported. It should be generating new addresses, and it will do this based on the seed stored in the wallet, which indicates the address type to create.

I created a new wallet and imported a mixture of legacy and bech32 addresses. Is "the seed stored in the wallet" a legacy seed or something? It would seem a newly created wallet would have a modern seed that can generate bench32 addresses.

Presumably, yes, the stored seed is one that makes legacy addresses. You can check by going to Wallet > Information and looking at the "Script type" field.

I see. It says p2pkh. It shows the xpub.
